# How can we add image in tweet intent URL to show image in twitter share popup

Tags: twitter

Hi we are using twitter intent to share our website content over twitter.

For this we are using this code;

```
$tweet="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=".$answer['Qna_answer']['first_name']." ". $answer['Qna_answer']['last_name'] ." &#58; ".$compTitle." " .$bitlyUrl;
```

So with this we are opening popup & now we want to add photo also in share pop[image]

I have searched for it but couldn't get any solution of it what need to  add in URL parameter to add photograph in popup box.

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to the same question but I get the feeling it's not possible. The closest thing I've seen is a Twitter card meta tag: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image which doesn't help when trying to share an image from a gallery on a page.